# какой будет fk если @OneToOne не указать @JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jpa

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User user;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стратегия именования по умолчанию - это имя поля отношения и имя поля первичного ключа, разделённые символом подчёркивания. То есть в вашем случае скорее всего `user_id`.